# MySQL/PHP Determine lowest values in table with multiple value columns

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have a table with columns like

id, name, c_price1, p_price2, c_price3, p_price4

I need to figure out a mysql query which will only search the c_price1 & c_price2 columns and return the lowest 5 values within the table that do not equal 0.00

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest giving [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and give your columns meaningful names (what's the different between price3 and price4, and c_price and p_price without knowing implementation details)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LEAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
  SELECT LEAST(t.c_price1, t.c_price2) AS lowest
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE LEAST(t.c_price1, t.c_price2) != 0.00
ORDER BY lowest
   LIMIT 5
```

Can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause, the earliest MySQL supports is the GROUP BY but that's not the case for all databases.

Answer (score 0):

untested:

select min(price1, price2) as our_min from some_table having our_min > 0 order by our_min limit 5;